# Creating a dictionary from an iterable

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the easiest way to create a dictionary from an iterable and assigning it some default value? I tried:

```
>>> x = dict(zip(range(0, 10), range(0)))
```

But that doesn't work since range(0) is  not an iterable as I thought it would not be (but I tried anyways!)

So how do I go about it? If I do:

```
>>> x = dict(zip(range(0, 10), 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration
```

This doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: Don't know enough about what you're using the dictionary for, but if the associated value is never really used for anything, consider using a Python `set` instead of a `dict`. With it you could just say `x = set(range(10))`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need the `dict.fromkeys` method, which does exactly what you want.

From the docs:

```
fromkeys(...)
    dict.fromkeys(S[,v]) -> New dict with keys from S and values equal to v.
    v defaults to None.
```

So what you need is:

```
>>> x = dict.fromkeys(range(0, 10), 0)
>>> x
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
```

Comment: Suppose that I want values equal to entries from some list, not a constant value. How to do? Something like this: `{0: y[0], 1: y[1], ... }` where `y` is a list.

Answer (score 35):

In python 3, You can use a dict comprehension.

```
>>> {i:0 for i in range(0,10)}
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0, 8: 0, 9: 0}
```

Fortunately, this has been backported in python 2.7 so that's also available there.

Comment: (upvoted) yes he did. 

well, the dict comprehension works on iterators, but i suggest changing "range(0,10)" to "iter(xrange(0,10))" which is an iterator, to make it "copy-and-paste-provable"

Answer (score 2):

PulpFiction gives the practical way to do it.  But just for interest, you can make your solution work by using `itertools.repeat` for a repeating 0.

```
x = dict(zip(range(0, 10), itertools.repeat(0)))
```

Comment: Actually you don't need `itertools` -- this will the same thing using the `iter()` built-in: `dict(zip(range(0, 10), iter(lambda:0,None)))` or even just this if the default desired is an int with a value of `0`: `dict(zip(range(0, 10), iter(int,None)))`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using the `defaultdict` subclass from the standard library's `collections` module. By using it you may not even need to iterate though the iterable since keys associated with the specified default value will be created whenever you first access them.

In the sample code below I've inserted a gratuitous `for` loop to force a number of them to be created so the following print statement will have something to display.

```
from  collections import defaultdict

dflt_dict = defaultdict(lambda:42)

# depending on what you're doing this might not be necessary...
for k in xrange(0,10):
    dflt_dict[k]  # accessing any key adds it with the specified default value

print dflt_dict.items()
# [(0, 42), (1, 42), (2, 42), (3, 42), ... (6, 42), (7, 42), (8, 42), (9, 42)]
```