# range of integers as key for dictionary

Tags: python

Is there a way to use a range of integers as a key in a dictionary? E.g.

```
numbers = {
 range(90,100) :'You're within 90 to 100' 
}
```

and then if I try to get a value using an integer, I want an output like this:

```
print(numbers.get(91))
'You're within 90 to 100'
```

and for values outside of dictionary, I want an output like:

```
print(numbers.get(101))
'You're not within 90 to 100'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Kind of: a) represent your range as a tuple, and b) write your own class.

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084749/creating-a-dictionary-from-an-iterable ?

Comment: Would it no be more logical in this case to use a simple if statement? If 90 < x < 100 print(win) else print(lose) maybe it's not valid for your purpose but if not how do you handle all other values, not in your dict ?

Comment: For values outside the range, you may want to consider a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to return an appropriate response if your input is outside the range

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ranges as keys. Following your logic, you can do the following:

```
numbers = { range(90,100) :'You re within 90 to 100'}

def look_for_x(x):
    res = [i for i in numbers.keys() if x in i]
    if len(res)==0:
        print('You are not in dictionary')
    else:
        print(numbers[res[0]])
```

Examples:

```
>>>look_for_x(91)
You re within 90 to 100
>>> look_for_x(102)
You are not in dictionary
```

Answer (score 1):

The dict and range approaches mentioned here are great. Why not try something simpler like.

```
def get_range(ranges, val):
    for rg in ranges:
        if val > rg[0] and val< rg[1]:
            return "you are within range"+str(rg[0])+"and"+str(rg[1])
    return "outside range"


print(get_range([[90,100],[100,110],[110,120]], 95))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your dict with:

```
numbers = {
    i : "You're within 90 to 100" for i in range(90,100)
}
```

This is a `dict` comprehension.  It will create an entry for each `i` in the range.

Note that I used double quotes for the string to avoid having to escape the `'` in `You're`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking up from another answer, you can also solve this problem for **all** invalid inputs with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

You can create a dictionary with a default factory that just returns your error message, and then set the correct keys with `update()` - that will change your dictionary in place.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


d = defaultdict(lambda: "Not in range 90-100")

d.update({i : "In range 90-100" for i in range(90,100)})

print(d[92])   # "In range 90-100"
print(d[111])  # "Not in range 90-100"
```